# When merging two sites together, how do I handle Google Search Console?

Tags: domains, google-search-console, migration

I'm setting up a website for a small e-commerce store. I had this website set with WordPress, with Google Search Console set up too.
What I then did is "join" 2 domain names ( having one pointing to the other one ).
Now we have decided to start from scratch, so use Shopify instead, which is now ready.

Since the previous website is actually indexed, how do I go about the new website? Do I need to cancel the previous and start from scratch with Google Search Console?

Comment: How do you go about WHAT for the new site?  What do you mean by "search console"? I am voting this question as unclear until you can clarify.

Comment: Search Console settings. I am creating an entirely new store on Shopify, getting rid of my old store in wordpress. The domain name is indexed, and my doubt is if I need to reset search console again since I am starting from scratch?

Comment: What search console are you talking about?

Comment: There is no reset functionality in Google Search Console

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - I didn't even know that Google Search Console was a thing

Comment: @Steve It used to be Google Webmaster Tools, but Google renamed it to encompass mobile apps.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller oh!  See how I have my finger on the pulse of the internet?  :o)

Answer (score 1):

I would not delete your old Google Search Console account. You can keep it around for troubleshooting purposes. First of all, it houses historical data. Second, if you see activity on it when there shouldn't be any, as unlikely as that is, you know there's an issue somewhere.

There's no special reset you need to perform with GSC. Just get your site set up in GSC the way you normally would: verify your ownership, set up your www and non-www versions and choose your preferred one, submit your sitemap. (I also advise doing the same in Bing Webmaster tools, so you can rank better there too, and submit your sitemaps and monitor for issues.) The one extra thing you may want to do is use the change of address tool in GSC, to signal to Google that your site has moved.

Outside of any webmaster tools application, you still need to make sure that your old website is properly redirecting to the new website: that you have a solid 301 redirect scheme in place, that your old pages are not appearing in SERPs (and that they're not resolving - they have to redirect, or go to 404 in some cases), that you're not seeing any serious traffic to your old site in Google Analytics (use a new tag for your new site), etc. Basically, work to get your old site out of the index, and for your new site to benefit from the old one's authority and link profile.

Comment: what If I already changed the account ID?

Comment: You're welcome!  Do you mean the GSC account? You can still perform most of the same steps, in terms of setting up your GSC and verifying your website, and redirecting from your old site to your new site, and practicing good SEO.